# How does the Rebel fleet at Endor compare to that at Scarif?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, return-of-the-jedi

How does the Rebel fleet at the Battle of Scarif compare to that at the Battle of Endor?

The Scarif fleet was painstakingly built up over the past 19 years but most of the larger ships were destroyed in the battle or after Vader's flagship arrived. The Endor fleet was made up of what remained and whatever they could recover within 3 years.

In comparison, how large are the two fleets? What type of ships do they have of each class (eg starfighters, frigates, cruisers, capital ships etc.)? What are they armed with?

Did the Alliance fleet recover from their losses at Scarif, and if so did they manage to expand and grow their fleet beyond what they had at Scarif?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Scarif vs http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Endor.

Answer (score 9):

> The Scarif fleet was painstakingly built up over the past 19 years but most of the larger ships were destroyed in the battle or after Vader's flagship arrived. The Endor fleet was made up of what remained and whatever they could recover within 3 years.
>
> Did the Alliance fleet recover from their losses at Scarif, and if so did they manage to expand and grow their fleet beyond what they had at Scarif?

Early on the rebellion is fragmented and localised. It has to litterally start from nothing.

We see this at the start of Star Wars: Rebels, there are just a few people with a shared hatred of the empire, working together to stir up trouble.

The battle of Scarif was the first time they had won a victory against the empire.

There is not so much in Disney cannon about what happens in the intervening years, but there are several things to consider.

- The existence (and destruction) of the Death star was a very polarising event.
- The galactic senate was dissolved which removed any semblance of representation.
- The rebellion is more publicly known of and their successes will make more people willing to help.

So while there is much less time to build a fleet, the capability and resources to do so would be much greater.